# Kinect as a webcam with MS SDK

Tags: camera, driver, webcam, kinect

Is there any posibility of using `Kinect` as a `WebCam`? I know that I can do that with `KinectCam.ax`, but it's only available on `OpenNI libraries`. I use `Microsoft Kinect SDK`, because of my project... I tried to find something in Internet... Nothing interesting...

I need a `WebCam` and it's a stupidity to buy a new one, when I have `Kinect` o_O

Comment: Why is it only for OpenNI? I haven't done that myself but they are using it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/4ee6e7ca-123d-4838-82b6-e5816bf6529c) and [here](http://lucabelluccini.blogspot.com/2011/11/kinect-as-webcam-on-your-pc.html) with the Beta SDK. Doesn't it work with the latest version?

Comment: It is obviously possible since people did it with the Beta, and the full version is better in most (well every) way

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to state it is a requirement to use the Microsoft Kinect SDK? E.g. "How do I...  with the Microsoft Kinect SDK"  Or if the parameters of your question are different than that, then say so. Yes, the Kinect device makes RGB camera data available over the USB cable. What are you really asking?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "webcam" as opposed to just a camera? Are you hoping for the device to just pop in as a camera that can be used by existing webcam software?

Comment: I want to use it with Skype/Facebook video chat/etc. I had some problems with KinectCam.ax. It didn't work for me. I will try again, thx for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone create the drivers to convert your kinect on a webcam. I test it, and works in Skype.

To install the kinect as a webcam download the 3 files (KinectCam.ax,install.bat, unistall.bat) in the Compiled folder here: 
https://github.com/wildbillcat/KinectCam/

Execute the install.bat as Administrator. And that's all.

The author say that this works even in Windows 8.
You can get more info on [this thread on msdn.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/4ee6e7ca-123d-4838-82b6-e5816bf6529c/)

Comment: Sorry, but I had to ask some1. It seems that my Windows is a little crashed, that's why I think I have problems. Nvm, because I need to do a format of C, so I will try Windows 8 from DreamSpark:))) Thanks for help

Comment: I tested it out on my `Windows 8 x64`, using the newest `Kinect SDK` from the official site and I can't load the `KinectCam.ax` module (downloaded from `KinectCam.ax` section on `github`, project official site). I tried to check dependencies (using `DependencyWalker`) and there were 2 files missing. I installed them manually and it didn't help:/

Comment: Probably the best person to help ypu with that is the author of the driver. Go to the thread on the msdn that I posted.

Comment: seems to not work with current Kinect SDK 1.8 version, may work with older ones, as talked about in the thread